# Manifolds for physicist

Tags: manifolds, physics, mathematical-physics

I'm a fourth year theoretical physicist taking a Manifolds course from the Maths department  at my Uni and I'm really struggling with the heavy maths and was wondering if there was a book which was aimed at physicists but was more in depth than Nakahara.

Comment: Several nice recommendations are given at [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61235/background-to-learn-about-manifolds).

Comment: I didn't notice the following book mentioned in the above post cited by @DietrichBurde ... https://books.google.com/books/about/Analysis_Manifolds_and_Physics_Revised_E.html?id=hUWEXphqLo8C And it might be a bit beyond what you're looking for, but you'll obviously have to decide all that for yourself.